# asp input field type date

Tags: html, asp.net

For simple html input we use:

```
<input type="date" placeholder="From" />
```

How can we use this method for asp field:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="from_date" runat="server" placeholder="From"></asp:TextBox>
```

when user clicks the field, calendar should appear.

Comment: The answer below is correct.

Answer (score 2):

**Question still unanswered:**

Here is even more detail to back up my answer:

**From Microsoft:** https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2468871

"New syntax lets you define a TextBox control that is HTML5 compatible. For example, the following code defines a TextBox control that is HTML5 compatible":

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="some-HTML5-type" />
```

-

**Original:**
I use asp.net and you can just use it like normal. An asp.net textbox ends up as a normal input element once processed by the server.

If you are using 4.0 or above you can just do :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="from_date" runat="server" placeholder="From" type="date"></asp:TextBox>
```

If you try this and it does not work, it is probably the browser you are using, type="date" is not supported by any IE, or any Firefox browsers, chrome is one of the only browsers that support type="date" right now.
See can i use for browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

I recommend that you find another option if you need browser support.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [AJAX Calender Extender](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/Calendar/Calendar.aspx)

```
<asp:TextBox ID="from_date" runat="server"  />
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="from_date" PopupButtonID="from_date">
</ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```

Comment: there is an error. how to fix this? **Parser Error Message:** Unknown server tag 'ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender'.

Comment: You need to register the assembly and import the namespace too in your page. **[here](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.in/2009/11/ajax-calendarextender-how-to-use.html)** is the compete guide for ajax extender.

Comment: i think this should have been a comment. It does not really answer the question on how to use type="date" in asp.net.

Comment: It's not a function or anything, it doesn't need formatting.